# view (or inside query) returns error because of a record that is not part of its result (??)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a strange issue with a query.
Here is a visual explanation of what happens, following is the textual description and the code to reproduce the problem.

a simple query containing the following inner join:

```
       TABLE 1                                           TABLE 2
   id        year   month       inner join          id       year    month
'2020.05'    2020   5           (on id)           '2020.05'  2020      5
'2020.05'    2020   5                             '8888.88'  8888      88
'2020.05'    2020   5
```

This query returns the three records with id '2020.05'
example :

```
SELECT table2.year, table2.month from QueryAbove
```

returns 3 times 2020,5 :

```
2020,5
2020,5
2020,5
```

the problem occurs if I add in the select the function:

```
SELECT datefromparts(year, month, 1), table2.year, table2.month from QueryAbove
```

Instead of returning 3 times 2020,5 it will fail because there is the unvalid value 88 for the `datefromparts` function in the month column of table2....(??) and although this record is not in the result.

This problem occurs to me starting with 3 records in table 1, with 2 or 1 it works fine.

The original query I have that experiences this problem has a lot more data and starts failing with 50 records, so if it works for you try adding more data in table 1 until it fails.

I could reproduce the problem with simple data, please find the code below.

I created a view that returns the result of the inner join query (but the problem still occurs without the view)

This looks like memory related, but I can't explain why and how this is occurring, and I would be very interested to understand this.

If someone knows what is going on, I thank you in advance for the information.
please tell me if more information is needed or if something is not clear in my explanation.

------ create tables -----

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_view') is not null
begin
drop view dbo.test_view
end

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.temp_fact') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE dbo.temp_fact
END
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.temp_dim') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE dbo.temp_dim
END
GO
create table temp_fact
(
  submission_bk varchar(30) not null
)

create table temp_dim
(
  submission_bk varchar(30) not null,
  [Submission_Year] int not null,
  [Submission_Month] int not null
)

insert into temp_dim
select '2020.05', 2020, 5 union all
select '8888.88', 8888, 88

insert into temp_fact
select '2020.05' union all 
select '2020.05' union all  
-- select '2020.05' union all 
select '2020.05'
```

---- create view ----------

```
create view test_view as (
   select 

   FACT.submission_bk as submission_id,
   s.Submission_Year,
   s.Submission_Month
   from temp_fact as FACT
   inner join temp_dim as s on s.Submission_BK = FACT.Submission_BK 
)
```

------ query the view -------

```
select 
  [submission_id],
  [Submission_Year],
  [Submission_Month],
  datefromparts(Submission_Year, Submission_Month, 1) as bdate
from test_view
```

Comment: SQL server query optimizer may decide to scan and compute formulas from some source table before joining. You should test validity of data somewhere (like `case when submission_month > 12 then 12 else submission_month end`).

Comment: T-SQL does not short-circuit and the engine reserves the right to rearrange operations as it sees fit for performance. All expressions in a T-SQL query must be valid for all rows in base tables, regardless of whether they're seemingly excluded by other parts of the query. To mitigate this `CASE` can be used -- even that occasionally fails but most of the time you can count on `CASE` clauses being evaluated only when the `WHEN` condition is true. `NULLIF` is another useful tool to ensure no error occurs (most expressions involving `NULL` simply yield `NULL`).

Comment: To extend on @JeroenMostert, you can force the order of execution with `OPTION(FORCEORDER)`

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts: `FORCE ORDER` enforces the order of joins, and that's all it does. It does *not* force an order of other query operators. If you're lucky that *may* ensure an otherwise invalid expression evaluation gets deferred, but it's not something that can be used in all cases, and even when it can forcing the join order can have a very detrimental effect on the performance of the query (there's a reason the engine rearranges them). So -- buyer beware.

Answer (score 2):

The logical evaluation of the query has nothing to do with this.  The "logical evaluation" really refers to the scoping rules used during the compilation phase.  Unfortunately, this part of the documentation has not bee updated in decades to clarify this point.

The SQL query itself is run as a directed acyclic graph (DAG).  The compilation and optimization phase constructs the graph from the original query.  And there is little similarity between the two.  That is, there is no "group by" node in the DAG; no "where" node in that DAG.

One of the consequences is that SQL Server moves operations around.  It often finds that running simple expressions *before* filtering is more efficient than running them *after* filtering.  And this results in errors such as the one you find.

Personally, I think this is a bug.  Your code should not generate an error, because it is valid on the data that you choose.  Alas, Microsoft does not agree with that interpretation.

Unfortunately, there is no `try_datefromparts()` function.  But you can use another `try_` function.  I would probably use:

```
try_convert(date, convert(varchar(100), year*10000 + month*100 + 1))
```

Comment: You are one of well-known and proved SQL Sever experts. I would like to see you improving this article!

Answer (score 0):

The interesting in such cases is that sometimes the statement will not rise an error.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement), the `Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement` is as follows:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

But sometimes, the engine may start performing an operation in the `SELECT` before other clauses are finished in order to optimize the query. This is also, pointed in the docs:

> The preceding sequence is usually true. However, there are uncommon
> cases where the sequence may differ.
>
> For example, suppose you have a clustered index on a view, and the
> view excludes some table rows, and the view's SELECT column list uses
> a CONVERT that changes a data type from varchar to integer. In this
> situation, the CONVERT may execute before the WHERE clause executes.
> Uncommon indeed. Often there is a way to modify your view to avoid the
> different sequence, if it matters in your case.

In your case, the following should solve the issue:

```
select 
[submission_id]
,[Submission_Year]
,[Submission_Month]
,datefromparts(Submission_Year,Submission_Month,1) as bdate
from test_view
WHERE TRY_CAST(CONCAT(Submission_Year, '-', Submission_Month, '-01') AS DATE) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: "Uncommon indeed" -- boy, those doc writers do have a twisted sense of humor sometimes. :-P If you ask the engine, it'd say the logical evaluation order of a statement is "more what you'd call guidelines than actual rules".

Comment: @JeroenMostert This page is a huge improvement. I remember the first time I met this issue - it was a nightmare to catch it. Also, now the docs are in the GitHub and everyone can improve them :-) you can click on the `Edit` button on the right up corner in the page ;)

Comment: I would, but a proper treatment of the subject might well exceed the page, especially if we wanted to be helpful and give query authors all the tools needed to actually diagnose and fix the issue. What's there now is quite bad, but at least it covers the ground, and it'd be petty to edit it just for the colorful choice of words.

Comment: @gotqn . . . "logical processing" of the query really has nothing to do with run-time query errors.  This section of the documentation is routinely misunderstood.  It is intended to explain the scoping of identifiers during the compilation phase.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, as it is pointed in the docs `The actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.` and this is what is happening - data that is going to be filtered is proceed in advance.

Comment: @gotqn . . . It is not "may vary".  It is that the so-called "logical execution" really really has nothing to do with the actual plan.  Perhaps Microsoft inherited this from Sybase when they bought the code base.